# Word 2007: Change the background to blue for all documents?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a user who needs to have the page color set to blue due to retinal damage.  At best we can change the background to blue for the document he's currently working on but we need to set up Word so that all documents he opens are defaulted to a blue background.  This works great in Office 2003.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This feature of bluebackground/white text (to emulate WordPerfect) was removed in Word 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you make use of the Accessibility features in Windows (e.g. a High Contrast colour scheme) or use colour inversion via the magnifier (at a factor 1:1)?

Changing the background colour of certain documents will affect all users who may have to view/process these documents.

Answer (score 0):

You are best off changing the `normal.dotm` file located in `%userprofile%\microsoft\templates`.

When you save this, any new file will open with whatever settings were saved in this file.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "all documents he opens" do you mean new documents (in which case normal.dotm as Wil says) or every document the user opens?

For the latter, I wonder if a macro could change the background colour when a document is opened?  You'd need to have the macro in all documents I suppose, and catch a BeforeSave event to change the background back from blue as the document was saved, so that other suers didn't get blue background.  Feels a bit hacky.

I guess the "proper" solution would be do do it as a Word Add-In, and somehow store the original background colour in the document properties and restore it BeforeSave.  Add-In development is beyond a simple bit of scripting or macro though.